# How to detect obtrusive text?

Tags: regex

Many people are tired of obtrusive words with no value, like these:

- f**king
- Id|ot
- <|>
- whaaaat????!!!!???

I plan to detect suspicious records and then to verify them manually. In other words, to find rules which detect that something is most likely obtrusive. Is there any reasonable solution? I am thinking about these REGEX rules:

```
\w\W+\w
\D{3,}
```

Is it worth the effort?

Comment: ˙sıɥʇ ƃuıʃpuɐɥ ʎʃʃɐɔıʇɐɯoʇnɐ ɟo ǝɔuɐɥɔ ɐ ǝʌɐɥ ʇ,uop ʎʃʃɐǝɹ no⅄

Comment: Even natural language parsing can't possibly catch a decent part, regex will fail spectacularly (btw, the first regex matches e.g. `o, m` in `Hello, my friend`)! If this really is a severe issue, consider reviewing everything via human moderators. (At least you just want to find records to be reviewed by humans, so you're not fully insane ^^).

Comment: @msw: This is great comment :-) Still I believe that many rude people don't have time and invention to write this masterpiece.

Comment: the only thing that can detect obtrusive text is... well, yourself. :-)

Comment: One man's obtrusive text is another tween's text message.

Comment: `flag this entry as noise, offensive or spam` is a good way to go.

Comment: @frank: yes, but only for phorums for registered users

Comment: @Jan Turoň: if it was difficult to do, I wouldn't have done it: http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down.htm?text=You+really+don't+have+a+chance+of+automatically+handling+this.

Comment: @msw: Now it is obvious. Thanks again :-)

Comment: And the inhabitants of Scunthorpe, among other places, would doubtless like to refer to where they live.  There are legitimate words and names that contain vulgar words, which makes the auto-detection of offensive language even more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Bayesian filtering featurizing misspellings that are combinations of alphas and other characters (e.g. all of the examples you've provided). This has the decided benefit that it "learns" over time, but needs to be fed an initial training set before it can produce useful results. To fit your needs you would set the threshold for matching low so you'd get false positives that you'd have to allow (and hopefully the algorithm would not allow through too many false negatives).

Toby Segaran's *[Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325)* provides a good explanation and Python code for making this work.

Comment: This seems promising. But according to other reasonable comments, I will try to avoid autodetects. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I think other comments are making the valid point it's always possible to defeat a detection algorithm. That noted, implementing something like this will make it much easier to detect the majority of offending items.